# how to Pass variable in link to the django view

Tags: python, html, django, mongodb

I have a html form which display data using a for loop.

```
<tbody id="table">
    {% for sku, lid, stk, mrp, sp, stts in product_data %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class="btn-link" href="/product/product.html" value="{{sku}}">{{sku}}</a>
        </td>
        <td>{{lid}}</td>
        .....
```

This code prints data in a table using a for loop with a link in first colyumn of table.
The link points to a new page where i want some data to be displayed.
Now The displayed data is dynamically generated from a mongodb database. I want when i click on the link it pass the value as a parametre to a django view so can fetch data which contains the parametre and show it on the next page. How to do that?

My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from inventory.models import GetProductData

def inventory(request):
    pd = GetProductData().skuData()
    sku = pd[0]
    listing_id = pd[1]
    stock_count = pd[2]
    mrp = pd[3]
    status = pd[5]
    selling_price = pd[4]

    product_data = zip(sku, listing_id, stock_count, mrp, selling_price, status)
    context_dict = {'product_data':product_data}
    return render(request, 'inventory/inventory.html', context_dict)

def product(request):
    return render(request, 'inventory/product.html')
```

Comment: what does the sku relate to? a model field? You can add a parameter to your url which is one of the first things the django tutorial shows how to do..

Comment: I read about it but couldn't figure out how to implement that

Comment: You should show what you have tried

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, its not advisable to use html name when you add a url. Instead of having

```
href="/product/product.html"
```

you could have just had something like

```
href="/product/"
```

so in your urls.py you should have it defined as below

```
url(r'^product/$', product),
```

where 'product ' is the corresponding view handling that request.

Now if you want to send some parameters to django from the html

render your template as below

```
<tbody id="table">
    {% for sku, lid, stk, mrp, sp, stts in product_data %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class="btn-link" href="/product/?sku={{ sku }}">{{sku}}</a>
        </td>
        <td>{{lid}}</td>
        .....
```

and in your view i.e; at products

```
def product(request):
    if request.method=='GET':
        sku = request.GET.get('sku')
        if not sku:
            return render(request, 'inventory/product.html')
        else:
            # now you have the value of sku
            # so you can continue with the rest
            return render(request, 'some_other.html')
```

Answer (score 9):

It can be done in 2 ways, using get and using URL parameter.

Using get is simply and flexible, but will lead to ugly URLs:

```
            <a class="btn-link" href="/product/product.html?parameter={{ your_parameter_here }}" value="{{sku}}">{{sku}}</a>
```

And inside view, you can access it like this:

```
def product(request):
    your_parameter = request.GET['parameter']
    return render(request, 'inventory/product.html')
```

Using url parameters is much better way, it is also more DRY than get parameters (especially when not using `{% url %}` tag with get).

Your urls.py should look like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^product/product-(?P<parameter>[\w-]+).html', 'views.product', name="product"),
]
```

Getting that parameter in view:

```
def product(request, parameter): # it's just passed as kwarg into view
    return render(request, 'inventory/product.html')
```

and creating URL in your template:

```
            <a class="btn-link" href="{% url "product" parameter=your_parameter_here %}" value="{{sku}}">{{sku}}</a>
```