# Bootstrap 4 navbar active class not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

In a website, I am trying to get this specific navbar active class to work. When I click on the current page, I would like the link to turn blue. Since I am a beginner, any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is the navbar :

```
<div class="nav-scroller py-1 mb-2">

   <nav class="nav d-flex justify-content-between">


      <a class="active p-2 text-muted" href="#"><b> Business</b> </a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#"><b> Design </b></a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#"><b>Travel </b></a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#"><b> Opinion </b></a>

   </nav>

</div>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
$('.nav .p-2 .text-muted').click(function(){
$('.nav .p-2 .text-muted').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
})
```

I also used CSS to turn the current navbar page link to blue:

```
.nav  > .p-2.activate  {
color:blue;
}
```

Comment: In your CSS you called the class `activate` and in your HTML and jQuery you called it `active`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working demo :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('nav a').click(function(){
   $('nav a').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
   let link=$(this).attr('href');
   window.location.href=link;
 });
});
```

```css
.nav >a.active>b{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    
    
    <div class="nav-scroller py-1 mb-2">

   <nav class="nav d-flex justify-content-between">


      <a class="active p-2 text-muted" href="https://fonts.google.com"><b> Business</b> </a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="https://facebook.com"><b> Design </b></a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="google.com"><b>Travel </b></a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#"><b> Opinion </b></a>

   </nav>

</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

you need to send `section="yourpagename"` from server side to frontend side ,

now you can show active link 2 ways :

1) first one is do ternary condition and add class in a tag

something like this way :

```
<a class="p-2 text-muted <% section=="Business"?'active':'' %>" href="#"><b> Business</b> </a>
```

2) second way is add active class using jQuery

```
 <a id="Business" class="p-2 text-muted" href="#"><b> Business</b> </a>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var section= "Business" . <--send value from server side same as link id
    $('#'+section).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this demo but it is working when I let the link empty (href = "#") what do you think could be the problem?

Comment: @ClaudeVernetMichel , check the updated answer

Comment: @ClaudeVernetMichel , which backend you are using ? php or nodejs ?

Comment: It sill not working, I am using Django 2.1

Comment: @ClaudeVernetMichel , please check updated answer

Comment: Sorry for asking so many questions, I am really new in web design and development. Do you know how to send section="yourpagename" in Django? Any link would be helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153593/passing-variable-from-django-template-to-view

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32690356/how-to-pass-variable-in-link-to-the-django-view

Comment: It is working, thank you so much! I changed my views.py and I aslo changed the a tag to get the url. Thanks again :)

Comment: Thanks! It is working with Boostrap 5! :D

Answer (score 0):

In your `JQuery` you added class named `active` ,but indise `css` you have class  `activated` . Change it to `active`

```
.nav > .p-2.active { color:blue; }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are making mistake to choose `selector`, add this

```
$('.nav .p-2.text-muted').click(function(){
  $('.nav .p-2.text-muted').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

and `css` also

```
.nav  > .p-2.active  {
color:blue;
}
```